# How to create a timeline chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-python, timeline

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a graph like this, with some Python library? If so, does anyone have any examples to share?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward using [plotly.express.timeline](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/). Look at the first example on that page. If you want it on one y-axis position like your screenshot then try

```
# example directly from Plotly
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-01-03'),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-01-03', Finish='2009-01-16'),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-01-16', Finish='2009-01-18')
])
# add color param and remove the y param from the example
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", color='Task')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is held in a `spreadsheet`, for more *flexibility*, you can use [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 3))

ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("none")

ax.set_xticks(df[["start", "end"]].stack().unique())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%M"))
ax.set_xlim(df["start"].min(), df["end"].max())
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_weight("bold")
    label.set_fontname("serif")

d = {"Status A": "#ff0000", "Status B": "#00b050", "Status C": "#0070c0"}

for s, c in d.items():
    tmp = df[df["status"] == s]
    ax.barh(tmp["y"], tmp["duration"], left=tmp["start"], height=0.2, color=d[s])

rects = [plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=c) for c in d.values()]

ax.legend(
    rects, d.keys(), ncol=len(d.keys()), bbox_to_anchor=(0.463, 1.25),
    frameon=False, handleheight=2, handlelength=3, handletextpad=0.5,
    prop={"weight": "bold", "family": "serif"},
)

plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

| status | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Status A | 12:00 | 12:45 |
| Status B | 12:45 | 13:10 |
| Status C | 13:10 | 13:40 |
| Status B | 13:40 | 14:15 |
| Status A | 14:15 | 14:40 |
| Status C | 14:40 | 15:10 |
| Status A | 15:10 | 15:45 |
| Status C | 15:45 | 16:00 |
| Status B | 16:00 | 16:30 |

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

df[["start", "end"]] = df[["start", "end"]].apply(pd.to_datetime, format="%H:%M") 
df["duration"] = df["end"] - df["start"]
df["y"] = 0.5 #to fake numeric y-values
```